# json jackson encoding - StackOverflowError

Tags: java, json, jackson, hl7-fhir

I'm trying to convert a java object to a json string and it fails with a StackoverflowError, probably because of an inifinite loop / cycle in the object's sub-objects.

```
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
...
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:655)
```

The object i'm trying to encode is an instance of a class I have no control of. I can only subclass it. I think i should be able to add `@JsonIgnore` on the guilty field (i mean on the corresponding overridden getter method) but I don't know which one it is. Those are huge classes with hundreds of fields and sub objects.

Is there an easy way to know  what field is causing the infinite loop in the json encoding?

PS: For those familiar with it, it is the `Patient` class of the Hl7 HAPI FHIR framework. I'm aware there is a custom json serialiser coming with that framework  but i need to use the more generic jackson one to leverage some of its features.

Many Thanks

Comment: Presumably you have a circular reference. Check the object for those and proceed from there.

Comment: yes, that's what i meant by "inifinite loop / cycle ". but my problem is how to find it in the hundreds of fields and sub objects of that instance :-)

Comment: If you don't need JSON, then Java serialization will deal with this itself. If you must have JSON then you likely have a long day of understanding what exactly it is you are serializing ahead of you...

Comment: I have the same issue which is a basic requirement. Would be nice to know where the issue comes from. (What in the FHIR patient graph make the json serialisation fails) ( spring boot 2.3.4.RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if your object graph has a circular dependency.  There's not really an easy way that I know of to find the cycle.  You can @Ignore everything, then re-introduce fields in batches and see where it breaks.

If you are subclassing simply to annotate with @Ignore, then you should look at [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) [Mixins](http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/?s=jackson%20mixin)

Answer (score 0):

Usually exception should still include inclusion graph (names of properties through which cycle formed); is this not the case here?

Comment: Nope :-(, the 3 first lines of the stack i posted in the question are repeated hundreds of time.

Comment: That is strange, since `BeanSerializer` does catch `StackOverflowError`, re-package as mapping exception, so while the depth of exception may be huge, the first line should indicate a bit about properties that form the cycle. Make sure to use a recent version (2.6.4 is the latest).